# A button is added to the navigation bar which is shown on all the screens. I need to hide it from all screens except one

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

In my app for iPad, I have first a welcome screen then home screen and then home screen navigates to rest of the screens. I have made a button on navigation bar of the home screen which takes the user back to the welcome screen. But that button is shown on all other screens as well. I want to remove that button from all the screens and show it only in the home screen. How can I hide that button from all other screens and make it visible only on the home screen?

Thanks PC

Comment: You think maybe you should accept some of the answers you've been given? You'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidDisappear:`

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; 
// or on whichever side your button is
```

In `viewWillAppear:`

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.showWelcomeButton; 
// self.showWelcomeButton is a retained UIBarButtonItem property
```

Comment: Hi Mundi,

Its not working this way. viewDidDisappear method is working fine but in viewWillAppear following  error appears:



"Request for member 'showInfoButton' in something not a structure or union".



is there any other way?

Comment: Make sure showInfoButton is retained (don't release it after adding it to the navigationItem). Better even, make it a @property of your view controller.